# windows batch file for run commands step by step

Tags: android, windows, command-line

for create android applications auto, in one step i have to sign `apk` by `apksigner` and keystore password

```
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.keystore my-app.apk
```

by run this command i get a message that give me a password

> Keystore password for signer #1:

but i need to run it by PHP or a windows batch file
for this job i must run this command with password in one line or somthing solutions for enter passwrod automatically. like this code:

```
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.keystore my-app.apk & 123456
```

or like this batch:

```
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.keystore my-app.apk
123456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
set "LF=^"
echo 123456%CR%%LF%| apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.keystore my-app.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use standard input, you can pass in the password via command-line (`--ks-pass pass:123456`), environment variable (`--ks-pass env:KEYSTORE_PWD`) or file (`--ks-pass file:password.txt`). See `apksigner sign --help` for more information.

Full example based on your OP:

`apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.keystore --ks-pass pass:123456 my-app.apk`

Answer (score 0):

Just use another argument:

```
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.keystore --ks-pass pass:yourpasswd my-app.apk
```

This is a inline option. To see other options, please take a look at this documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner